# micronaut-spring and spring-boot-actuator, can't access /actuator endpoints

Tags: groovy, spring-boot-actuator, micronaut

Just trying out micronaut with Spring capability, and can't get access to my /actuator endpoints Spring Boot v2.3.0 release and micronaut 2.0.0.M3

I created a basic micronaut project using the `mn create-app xxx --lang groovy`.

I have then added the spring dependencies and micronaut-spring and associated annotation processors.

My build.gradle now looks as follows

```
plugins {
    id "groovy"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
    id "application"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.21"  //enables annotation preproccessing support
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.21"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.3.0.RELEASE"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
}

ext['groovy.version'] = '3.0.4'

version "0.1"
group "com.softwood"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly 
}

dependencies {

    //annotation processors
    annotationProcessor platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut.spring:micronaut-spring-boot-annotation"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut.spring:micronaut-spring-web-annotation"
    testAnnotationProcessor "io.micronaut.spring:micronaut-spring-web-annotation:2.0.1"

    //latest groovy v3
    implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.4' //, ext: 'pom'

    //spring
    compileOnly "io.micronaut.spring:micronaut-spring-annotation:2.0.1"
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation group: 'io.micronaut.spring', name: 'micronaut-spring-web', version: '2.0.1'
    runtime ("io.micronaut.spring:micronaut-spring-boot:2.0.1")


    compileOnly platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    implementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime-groovy"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    testCompileOnly platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M2-groovy-3.0") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "com.softwood.Application"

//added - enable incremetal compile feature - can't enable with annotation processors !
/*tasks.withType(GroovyCompile).configureEach {
    options.incremental = true
}*/

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.forkOptions.jvmArgs.add('-Dgroovy.parameters=true')
}


shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
    jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
}
```

I have adjusted a HelloController as follows

```
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint


@Controller("/hello")
@Endpoint
class HelloController {

    @Get("/")
    String index() {
        return 'hello william'
    }
}
```

and marked the Application class as being a SpringbootApplication - but call the Micronaut.run() to build the MN context etc

```
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@CompileStatic
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Micronaut.run(Application)
    }
}
```

I tried to adjust application.yml to expose all the endpoints as follows

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut-std-app

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include=*:
```

This all compiles ok, and runs ok.  if you invoke the `localhost:8080/hello` you get the expected string

if you try and access the actuator endpoints - nothing is being generated, and the browser displays

```
{"message":"Page Not Found","_links":{"self":{"href":"/actuator/health","templated":false}}}
```

if your trying to do a mixed micronaut and spring project, then how do you get any actuator endpoints enabled for your MN pre processed controllers etc ?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a health check endpoint, Micronaut have build in health check endpoint available.

Add in the build.gradle the fallowing dependence to add the endpoints like health:

```
implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-management")
```

You can add in the application.yml

```
endpoints:
    health:
        enabled: true
```

Then change the health check url to "/health"

Comment: I'll try that, however as Spring actuator is in the class path - doesn't MN just let the standard spring actuator endpoints work?  it looks like an oversight, or something not been called via the Micronaut.run () method.  Isnt the standard spring capability reusable here ?

Comment: Part of spring is usable with Micronaut, like Spring data, Spring annotations and so on. But I'm not sure everything is usable. And with Micronaut newest version, almost everything you can do with Spring can be done natively by Micronaut